# how to use type Date and read the value from keyboard in java

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans-7

I have a problem with type Date in java.
how to alter this code to be able to get birth date from keyboard?

```
    Date birthDay;
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    birthDay=(Date)s.nextLine();
```

error : inconvertible types!

how to solve this ??

Comment: how has this to do with mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following code:

```
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                 new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy"); 
    df.setLenient(false);

    try {
        System.out.print("ENTER DATE STRING (mm/dd/yyyy ): ");
        String dateString = reader.readLine();
        // Parse the date
        Date date = df.parse(dateString);
        System.out.println("Original string: " + dateString);
        System.out.println("Parsed date    : " + date.toString());  
    }
    catch(Exception e) {

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to parse the input string like:

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String next = s.next("[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{4}");
try {
    Date birthDay = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").parse(next);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I used s.next(pattern) because it validates the input string, and if it does not match the pattern, it will throw a InputMismatchException

Comment: Might as well add some error checking so that the program prompts the user with the right format and asks for the date again, in case of a bad format.